# pandas dataframe updating values on a condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe called `project_layers` it has a column named `ID`.
I'm copying the `ID` values from `project_layers` to `gdf['wsiintid']`
A straight copy would be:

```
gdf['wsiintid'] = project_layers['ID']
```

However, there are a few empty `''` values, so I want to update these values based on a condition
I have to figure out the actual value based on some joins, but that's another issue outside the scope of this question.

```
    for layer in project_layers['ID']:
        if layer == '':
            print('value missing')
            gdf['wsiintid'] = <some value>
        else:
            # add in the value from project_layers['ID']
```

How do I achieve this?

EDIT

Current output

```
data = {'a column':  ['a value', 'a value', 'a value', 'a value',],
        'wsiintid': ['012', '', '', '017'],
         ....
        }
```

Result output

```
data = {'a column':  ['a value', 'a value', 'a value', 'a value'],
        'wsiintid': ['012', 'Y', 'Q', '017'],
         ....
        }
```

Y and Q added as placeholders for some real value, there could be many `''` instances. So the logic: for this row are there any `''` values, if yes then do some calculation to get a value (not shown here) and insert that value in the `wsiintid` column instead of the `''` value. Look at the next row, apply the same logic.

Comment: is it as simple as `df['column name'] = df['column name'].replace(['old value'],'new value')` testing now

Comment: Except the above would replace all `''` values with the same value, in the loop I aim to look up a real value, different for each

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected output?

Comment: example added and a rephrasing of the question below that

Comment: Do you need your loop solution? What is logic for `<some value>` ?

Comment: I need to update each instance of `''` with a different value, e.g. a list ['1','d','bob', ...] if that doesn't need a loop great. The `<some value>` really doesn't matter at this stage, it is derived from another column in the dataframe.

Comment: Ok, so instead `'',''` is possible defined list `L = ['Y','Q']` for replace ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [numpy.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). You can do something like

`np.where(project_layers['ID']=="", <some value>, project_layers['ID'])`

Comment: Does that do the same as `.replace()` ? how would that be applied in a loop. So for the 1st instance `''` should be replaced with `5`, the second instance a `b`, third instance - whatever value of the calculation (not show here for simplicity).

Comment: In `np.where(condition, x, y)` you can use any vectorwise calculation for x and y.

Comment: I've updated the question - see after the edit, it might make the question clearer and explain the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

This does the job

```
    for line, row in enumerate(gdf.itertuples(), 1):
        if row.wsiintid == '':
            gdf.at[row.Index, 'wsiintid']='xxx'
```

I can add a variable rather than 'xxx' once I have the calculation of that added to this.